# Is this topological space Hausdorff? Connected? Quasi-compact?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topology $\tau \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ defined as follows:

$$
U \in \tau \iff 0\notin  U \text{, or } [0, 1] \subset  U
$$

Is the topological space $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ a Hausdorff space? Is  $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ connected ? Is $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ quasi-compact?
Is

$$
f \colon (\mathbb{R},\tau) \to  (\mathbb{R}, \tau),
x \mapsto \frac{x}{2}
$$

a homeomorphism?

Comment: No thoughts at all? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you give us more information? In what context did this question come up? (That is more of a personal interest.) And, as Henno already mentioned: Please show us everything you have! It will help us to give you on-point help (because we know where you are) and it will prevent users from down-voting (which they do because "StackExchange is not a Please-Do-My-Homework site").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

What are the open sets that contain $0$? What does it mean for Hausdorffness?

Can you think of sets that are both open and closed?

Can you find an infinite cover of $X$? Does it have a finite subcover?

$f$ is clearly a bijection. What is the image of the open set $[0,1]$ under $f$?